# Migrate from one set of bare git repositories to another

Tags: git

We are migrating our 'web repository manager' software to another solution.

I have created all git repositories in the new system by going through an intermediary repository on my local machine e.g.

```
for each repo:
    git clone --mirror ssh://oldplace/repo.git
    git push --mirror ssh://newplace/repo.git
```

The time for the final cut over is approaching, and we will soon make the old system read-only. After that, what is a *correct* way get all new changes from the old system to the new system?  I want to make sure that no commits/tags/branches/whatever are missed. Please note, we have no hooks to worry about. Additionally, there are no commits in the new repos to worry about.

If I can follow the original process outlined, that would be fine. It may not be the fastest, but it's already scripted/working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to work well enough. There is one issue that I would like to bring to your attention though. If somebody pushes to the new repository, then the mirror pushes no longer work.

Another optimization would have been to simply do the mirror pushes from the original bare repos. We did not do that though, because the scripts we had in place were already working and it was a largely one-shot process.